# Using Internetexplorer com object how to simulate a drag and drop?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, powershell, com, drag-and-drop

There are plenty of examples that use JQuery but I cant find a sample code to simulate a drag and drop using the com interface of internet explorer.

[image]

```
$ie=New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application  
$ie.Visible=$true
$ie.Navigate("http://www.asharepointsite.com")
```

then what ? from the web developper tools the drop event seems to be handle by the body, so I tried `$ie.Document.body.dragDrop()` but the response was *False*

Subsdidiary question, how to inspect element with developper tools when you have to "over" it ?